# How to upload and keep updating the file in python

Tags: python, json, blockchain, bitcoin

I'm currently working on a blockchain type app in Python. And I'm storing all my transactions and blockchain stuff in a Json file. And every user will have the copy of it. I want to keep updating the blockchain so every transaction is on it. How can I do that?

Comment: Please give us more details about your question. What's the JSON file structure?, Have you tried something?, What's the Python version you are using?. Do you have a code working so far?. Please review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i didnt try something. im using python 3.9 And i do have a code working